# == operator overloading c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

So I have a class TreeNode

```
class TreeNode {
  private:
    TreeNode *left;
    TreeNode *right;
    unsigned frequency;
    unsigned char val;
  public:
    TreeNode(unsigned char val, unsigned int frequency);
    TreeNode(int value, unsigned int frequency);
    friend bool operator==(const TreeNode &a, const TreeNode &b) {
      return (a.getFrquency() == b.getFrequency() && a.getVal() == b.getVal());
    }
    bool isLeafNode(); // True if node is a leaf node, false otherwise
    void join(TreeNode *left, TreeNode *right); // Puts left as the left child and right as the right child of this node
    TreeNode* getLeft(); //returns the left child
    TreeNode* getRight(); //returns the right child
    unsigned getFrequency(); //returns frequency member variable
    unsigned getVal(); //returns val member variable
};
```

I am trying to override the == operator but for some reason I am always false. I don't think that I am overriding correctly. This is the scenario I am using it in:

```
int main (int argc, char** argv){
  MinHeap *mh = new MinHeap();
  TreeNode *n = new TreeNode(0, 0);
  mh->insert(n);
  TreeNode *m = mh->removeMin();

  if (m == n) {
    std::cout << "They are equal" << std::endl;
  } else {
    std::cout << "They are not equal" << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I keep getting `They are not equal` as my output.Any idea where I am going wrong?

fyi: All methods in MinHeap and TreeNode work correctly so the issue is not the class methods themselves.

Comment: You are comparing TreeNode pointers, not TreeNode objects.

Comment: Wait, are you comparing pointers ? Addresses of the nodes ?

Comment: Operator overloaded for `class TreeNode` works for instances of the class, but not for pointers to instances of the class. Since both `m` and `n` are pointers, you need to add their dereference before comparison in order to trigger a call to your custom `operator ==`. Currently, "raw" pointers are compared for equality.

Comment: Change `if (m == n)` to `if (*m == *n)` Voting to close for typo.

Comment: It is not clear how the memory manegement/ownership is implemented in that tree. Since `m` and `n` are different pointers, it is not clear where the second object suddenly came from. There's only one `new` in the program. Does the tree make copies? And yet implementes "by pointer" insertion and return semantics? Chances are the code will not "work" even after change to `*m == *n`  becuase one of the pointers is dangling. And if the three does not make copies, then I'd expect `m` and `n` to be equal here.

Comment: That is how they are being compared in my test cases so I am not able to change any part of the main.cpp file

Comment: @croth: Sorry, but your `main.cpp` does not have anything to do with your `==` operator. If you "not able to change any part of the main.cpp", it will never have anything to do with your `==` operator. So, the question is: what exactly are you trying to test here?

Comment: In fact, it is quite possible that the test was designed specifically to test that the tree will return the same pointer that was inserted into it originally. I.e. in a properly working teree `m` should be equal to `n` here. If the pointers are different, then the tree is not working properly (contrary to the OP's belief that "all methods work correctly"). This, of course, still has nothing to do with the above `==` operator. And if this is true. then this is NOT a diplicate.